# Programmatically Format Generated CodeDom Code

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

How can I make sure the CS generated from code like the following is formatted nicely, i.e as if we pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>? It is C#

We are doing something along the lines of:

```
CodeMemberMethod membMethod = new CodeMemberMethod();
membMethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Static | MemberAttributes.Public;
membMethod.ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference("IEnumerable<" + TableNameAsSinglular + ">");
membMethod.Name = "Get" + TableName;
membMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement(DataBaseContext + " dcontext = new " + DataBaseContext + "(ConnectionString);"));
membMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement("var records = from record in dcontext." + TableName + " select new " + TableNameAsSinglular + "{"));
    int iCount = 0;

    //Add columns fields
    foreach (DataRow dr in sqlTable.Rows)
    {
        if (iCount == 4)
        break;
        string strColName = dr["ColumnName"].ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        membMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement(strColName + "=" + "record." + strColName + ","));
        iCount++;
    }

membMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement("};"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeDom is really for runtime code generation. If you are looking to generate code at design time or compile time, you should use T4 templates.

T4 lets you format the code output exactly how you want it to appear:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: ah ok, that's interesting. We are (maybe were!) using codeGenerator.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(cnsCodeDom, sw, cgo); to write out to the file.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, go to

Tool -> Opetions-Text Editor->C#-> Formatting

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will use the settings there to format the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the question to reflect that I want to achieve this programmatically, Ideally at the same time we are writing the CodeDom code. I.e is there something like CodeDom.FormatNicely